# How can I return jsx after a couple of seconds in a turnery operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im using a turnery operator like this :

```
{
  typeof weather.data !== "undefined" ? (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 border">
        <Details
          temp={Math.round(weather.data.main.temp)}
          city={weather.data.name}
          country={weather.data.sys.country}
          date={dateBuilder}
          weather={weather.data.weather[0].main}
        />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  ) : (
    setTimeout(() => {
      return (
        <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center w-100 font">
          <img style={{ width: "100px" }} src={require("./assets/wifi.png")} />
          <p className="mt-3">Please check your internet connection</p>
        </div>
      );
    }, 3000)
  );
}
```

The problem is the If typeof weather.data is equal to undefined it doesn't return

> Please check your connection

part after 3 seconds basically the setTimeout function doesn't work .

So how can I return value after a couple of seconds using setTimeout ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a timeout to update a flag in state to show the JSX element

```
const connFail = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ connFail: true });
    }, 3000);
};
```

```
{
  typeof weather.data !== "undefined" && (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-12 border">
        <Details
          temp={Math.round(weather.data.main.temp)}
          city={weather.data.name}
          country={weather.data.sys.country}
          date={dateBuilder}
          weather={weather.data.weather[0].main}
        />
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  ) : connFail()
}
{
  this.state.connFail && (
    (
      <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-center w-100 font">
        <img style={{ width: "100px" }} src={require("./assets/wifi.png")} />
        <p className="mt-3">Please check your internet connection</p>
      </div>
    );
  )
}
```